# How to access the wamp server localhost in android using wifi router without internet

Tags: android, localhost, wifi, wampserver

How to access the wamp server localhost in android using wifi router without internet
I am trying this but it is not working
apache server

> AllowOverride none
>       Require all granted

Answer (score 0):

Access to 192.168.1.1 and see your ip. 
EX: 
I access wamp server: 192.168.1.100
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yX1w1.png

Comment: my server ip is 192.168.1.12 and my android devices ip is 192.168.1.15 when enter the my server ip in android device browser it doesn't show  anything